# Is it possible to ignore a model property in nswag without using [JsonIgnore]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, nswag

Using JsonIgnore is not possible in my project and [OpenApiIgnore] does not work. In swashbuckle it was possible to make a filter by its own attribute, but in NSwag I did not find a similar mechanism.

Code example:

Command class On API Gateway:

```
[MessageNamespace("identity")]
    public class UpdateUser:ICommand
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public UpdateUser(string surname, string name, string middleName, string department, string position, string adAccount, string email, string userName, string password)
        {
            Surname = surname;
            Name = name;
            MiddleName = middleName;
            Department = department;
            Position = position;
            AdAccount = adAccount;
            Email = email;
            UserName = userName;
        }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Guid Id { get; }
        
...
        
    }
```

Command  class on microservice:

```
 public class UpdateUser:ICommand
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public UpdateUser(Guid id, string surname, string name, string middleName, string department, string position, string adAccount, string email, string userName, string password)
        {
            Id = id;
            Surname = surname;
            Name = name;
            MiddleName = middleName;
            Department = department;
            Position = position;
            AdAccount = adAccount;
            Email = email;
            UserName = userName;
        }
        
        public Guid Id { get; }
...
        
    }
```

Api method on gateway:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
[JwtAuth(Roles.Administrator)]
public async Task<ActionResult> Put(Guid id, UpdateUser command)
{
    //Send command to RabbitMQ(serialized)
    //Id binded before sending but after construct in service ID is missing
    await SendAsync(command.Bind(c => c.Id, id));
    return Accepted();
}
```

Why i need to remove property from NSwag generation?
Because i need Id in route, but if Id also located in query body it's makes my front-end coder aggressive and destructive хD and also it's not beautiful:
[image: nswag generation]

Comment: Can you elaborate on why using [JsonIgnore] is not possible?

Comment: @MindSwipe it's command from api(parameter in api method) serialize and send to RabbitMQ. And jsonignore remove my property from serealized rabbitmq command

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about NSwag, but it's very likely possible for you to write your own [Json.Net Contract Resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)

Comment: You have a model class for your API that contains an unwanted property for the API, right? Sounds like violating [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: @SirRufo no. i use cqrs commands for microservices. I add code example in question.

Comment: As I say, it violates SRP

Comment: @SirRufo why? it's only command. not model. It's like dto. One command/query for one action but copy-pasted in gateway and microservice. Only command/query handlers use IRepository<T> for accessing to model. Maybe i don't fully understand what's is violating Single Responsibility Pattern in my architecture

Comment: You use a single class for two cases (API contract, CommandHandler) and both might change, so we have possible **more than one reason** to change the class -> violating SRP. Thats it. Use a class for each case and your problem with the unwanted property has gone, solved by SRP

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks for the great explanation. I'll think about it. It just turns out triple duplication of the same code: API contract for gateway, command on gateway and command on the microservice. But yes, without an additional class contract, I still can’t get rid of the loss of property during serialization

Comment: No, look at my answer, there is not more duplication as you already have ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to use separate classes

```
namespace API.Models
{
  public class UpdateUser
  {
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
  }
}

namespace Domain.Commands
{
  public class UpdateUser:ICommand
  {
    [JsonConstructor]
     public UpdateUser(Guid id, string surname, string name, string middleName, string department, string position, string adAccount, string email, string userName, string password)
     {
       Id = id;
       Surname = surname;
       Name = name;
       MiddleName = middleName;
       Department = department;
       Position = position;
       AdAccount = adAccount;
       Email = email;
       UserName = userName;
     }

     public Guid Id { get; }
...

  }
}
```

and in the controller

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
  public class UserController
  {
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [JwtAuth(Roles.Administrator)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Put(Guid id, API.Models.UpdateUser command)
    {
      //Send command to RabbitMQ(serialized)
      //Id binded before sending but after construct in service ID is missing
      var cmd = new Domain.Commands.UpdateUser( id, command.Surname, command.Name, ... );

      await SendAsync(cmd);
      return Accepted();
    }  
  }
}
```

The Domain.Commands can be placed inside a class library and used by API and Microservice as well.

Comment: yea, my bad! i said it wrong... no duplication of course! Big thx for creating code example. My code now really similar to your. But what about shared code between microservices and api via separate assembly / classes ? I read what is it antipattern. What do you think about it?